# A simple array in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

There are many (many) examples of drawing arrays in Tikz.
However, all of them are complicated, and none work for me.
Here is the simplest thing I found, but it's still not working.
The context is a `beamer` presentation (but I'm not sure it matters)

EDIT: inlined everything to a single `main.tex` as suggested in the comments. Also added the missing `\\`. Still no go

```
$ cat main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{greatest author out there}

\frame{\titlepage} 

%\input{slide.tex}

\frame{ %%%% EDIT FORM ANSWER: this line is redundant
\frametitle{Lovel Tikz Array}
\begin{frame} %%%% EDIT FORM ANSWER: this line should go before the frametitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix { 1 \& 2 \& 3 \& 4 \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
} %%%% EDIT FORM ANSWER: this line is redundant

\end{document}
```

The command I'm using is a simple `$ pdflatex main.tex`

Comment: please from your code fragments compose single small self contained document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I fear that the fact slides themselves don't have the `\usepackage` directive might somehow cause problem

Comment: You will certainly need \\ in `\matrix { 1 \& 2 \& 3 \& 4\\ };`.

Comment: You are nesting a \begin{frame} inside a \frame. That is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect, that you will provide something an MWE like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lovely Tikz Array}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (m)  [matrix of math nodes]
{ 
1 \& 2 \& 3 \& 4 \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which privide nice result, at least to my opinion. However, your code fragments have more flaws. Compare code for frame with matrix in my MWE and your MWE.

[image]

**addendum:**
Considering your comment, below is an example for matrix with brackets as delimiters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Lovely Tikz Array}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (m)  [matrix of nodes,
              nodes={text depth=0.5ex},  
              left delimiter={[},
              right delimiter={]}
              ]
{
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I inlined `slide.tex` into `main.tex`. You're right, the problem still persists.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom, where? My MWE works fine and give nice result (now added). As I understood your question, my answer solve your problem :-)

Comment: Yes, problem solved, thanks. Would it be too greedy to ask how can one draw the array cell borders?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom, usually help to read documentation :-). See *59.3 Delimiters* on pages 702-703. I add an example to my answer.